# understanding node package manager and how applications are launched/run

Tags: node.js, npm

[clearly a noob question]  Fundamentally, I don't have a proper mental model of npm and how the packages get **properly** installed, running and subsequently invoked.

I will illustrate with two examples. Working through these issues ought to improve this (lacking) mental model.

For example, I installed [this package](https://github.com/mapbox/makizushi) in a directory called `npm`.  On first install there were some complaints form the installer.  Recalling the install procedure returns just one error which I had not picked :  `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Volumes/Mo/Users/main/r/npm/package.json'`  My understanding was that npm installs a directory `node_modules` within which it installs the called package and slew of dependancies.  Within the directory of the package `@mapbox/makizushi`is the package.json file.

If I `cd` to the above directory in the console, then launch the first command as suggested by the package:

```
node
> var makizushi = require('makizushi');
Thrown:
{ Error: Cannot find module 'makizushi'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Which is odd as the files are installed and the console is launched from its directory...

Second example, using [this repository](https://github.com/webgeodatavore/express-simplestyle-spec/).  I tried both by downloading and launching `npm install` and with the full command `npm install @webgeodatavore/express-simplestyle-spec`

On first install, a number of errors are given, for example:

```
> mapnik@3.7.2 install /Volumes/Mo/Users/dvodvo/r/npm/express-simplestyle-spec-master/node_modules/mapnik
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
[...]
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/Mo/Users/main/r/npm/express-simplestyle-spec-master/node_modules/mapnik
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
[...]
npm WARN @webgeodatavore/express-simplestyle-spec@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN @webgeodatavore/express-simplestyle-spec@0.2.0 No license field.
[...]
npm ERR! mapnik@3.7.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Failed at the mapnik@3.7.2 install script.
```

I do recall this error popping up in the first case (a while back).

So how does one recover from such dependancy issues? If installer directs installation to directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/` what is the point of the `package.json` complaint?  Assuming proper installation, how does the package get invoked and under which path?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency issue is a downside to npm, dependencies make things a little bloated. Unfortunately, if the packages are not published correctly, not much can be done. Without knowing full context what would happen if you run:

```sh
mkdir project
cd project/
npm init -y
npm install makizushi
```

The `npm init -y` command will create the `package.json` file for you within the current directory. The package.json is the "manifest" that npm will read when it comes to installing all dependencies of a project (as well as a source for cool things like deploy scripts, versioning, and other publishing goodies). The `npm install makizushi` will then write the package at the right version to the package.json file and then create a `node_modules` folder.

The older way to install a dependency as just a project specific dependency is:

```sh
npm install --save makizushi
```

While most recent versions of npm do not require this, IMO it helps comprehend exactly where this package will be installed as opposed to the 2 other places a package can be installed: globally and just a development dependency.

```sh
npm install -g makizushi
npm install --save-dev makizushi
```

Comment: Interestingly, install makisuzhi generated error `npm ERR! mapnik@3.5.14 install: 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'  [...] Failed at the mapnik@3.5.14 install script.`.  Thus the process is failing for the exact same dependancy, but for an older version here.  I suppose at this point I should be digging for a version of mapnik to install globally...

Comment: Did you try installing a prior version?

Comment: this is where is gets slippery for me (ruby gems is my ballpark ;-) ).  I am now suspecting that my OS X version (10.9.5) is what is clogging things up.  Should I simply run `npm install mapnik` and npm will recognize which version is adaptable to this version of the OS? on page https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/blob/master/.travis.yml#L19-L47  there are references to Xcode, as of 8.2 but not the one running locally (6.2).  Sounds like I shoudl spin up a VPS and set up npm and the package there, eh?

Comment: I also came from the ruby world! `npm install lodash@4.17.4` would install lodash (a popular package for data manipulation) at then version 4.17.4. That command runs and then you will see "lodash":"^4.17.4" on the package.json file.

Comment: will give it a whirl!

Comment: I also came from ruby world! Install a specific version (e.x. `npm install lodash@4.17.4` would install lodash at version 4.17.4). Installing node and npm should wipe out the OS version concern. If you are in the project directory with the package.json, it will install all of the packages you need.

Comment: Local OS seemed to create incompatibilities.  Installing on a VPS ran as expected.  However, cannot reach objects! in configuring nginx `server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    location ~/npm/markers {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; [...]`   I get a response at the ip address. When following instructions on page https://github.com/webgeodatavore/express-simplestyle-spec/  and pass the string of URL schema I get a 404.  between app.js and index.js what should one be pointing at? I certainly have the location wrong.